# Lagrange Multiplier Scenario with Different $\lambda$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum values  of $f(x,y)=y^2-4x^2$  about the constraint: $x^2+2y^2=4$

When I do the usual Lagrange Multiplier method, the equations come out rather strange:
$\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ where $g$ is the constraint.

$-8x=\lambda2x$ and $2y=\lambda4y$

which yields different values for $\lambda$. How do I go about solving for the optimization points when this happens?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there something really basic that I am missing here, seeing the downvotes?

Comment: I am not a downvoter, but your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, consider editing the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: That is what the problem is, there is nothing more to it.

Comment: I don't think that it's a bad question, but if you are not providing details it could look like you are just asking a "homework" question. Most users here prefer that you really want to learn or understand, not just get an answer. That being said, a hint is that $\lambda$ is only different if it is not trivially satisfied. (I.e.  this means either $x$ or $y$ is $0$)

Comment: Well, I would normally solve for $\lambda$ in another problem, and eliminate it, then solve for x and y. Here this does not work.

Comment: I do see that either could be zero, so what can I do with that? Do I set one variable equal to zero, and use the g equation to solve for either x and y?

Comment: Take a look at this question I asked. Very similar problem. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176281/minimizing-a-quadratic-function-subject-to-quadratic-constraints